# handlebars "include" "partial" ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I would like to abstract out pieces of html in an ember project.

For example... keep the `<head>` in a different file and "include" it in `index.hbs` or something. (think php `<?php include('something'); ?>`)

The naming conventions in ember CLI and handlebars are a little foreign so far - and I'm not finding what I thought would be pretty standard...

My guess would have been `{{#include 'head.hbs'}}' or something

There has got to be a convention for this... But I think I'm using the wrong search terms.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.ember-cli.com/#resolving-from-template-helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `{{render 'your-template-file'}}` or `{{partial 'your-partial-file'}}` to accomplish this.